# Submitting My Website's Contact Form to Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to use Google's AppMaker for G Suite to receive contact form submissions from my website.

Ideally the form would submit a POST request to AppMaker, but I haven't been able to find any way to POST data from an external service - only fetching.

Is it possible to send data from a standard HTML form (NOT a Google Form) to an AppMaker endpoint, or is there a way to use Sheets as a Datasource and accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**

*>> I would like to use Google's AppMaker for G Suite to receive contact form submissions from my website.*

**A1**

I would recommend connecting your App Maker application to Cloud SQL and share data between your Web Site and App Maker using the same database.

**Q2**

*>> Ideally the form would submit a POST request to AppMaker*

**A2**
If you chose to go down this way you can face number of obstacles (the first one is authentication). Here is discussion on google groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/H3Pyd0SJreg

**Q3**

*>> is there a way to use Sheets as a Datasource and accomplish the same thing?*

1. The easiest way to use spreadsheet is importing data to your model,
   but afaik it is one-time manual operation.
2. In theory you can implement synchronization algorithm that will sync
   your model(s) with some sheet(s) and setup a trigger to call it...
   sounds too complex to me...I would not recommend to move in this
   direction, unless you have no other options.
3. Another option with spreadsheets is creating Calculated Model and using App Script Spreadsheet API to pull/push data:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

**Summary**

Sharing Cloud SQL database between your Web Site and App Maker app sounds like simplest solution to achieve desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the group discussion link. The website is hosted on Firebase - just wanted to confirm that I could store the form submission in Firebase DB, and then use Firebase Messaging to queue data for App Maker? Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you end up having to synchronize multiple sheets you can check out SheetGo. It's an add-on for sheets that works really well.

https://www.sheetgo.com/

Answer (score -1):

You could create a google form and read the form entries from a google sheet to App Maker.